# Error on Xpath in Eclipse, copied the xpath from chrome and when i give in eclipse it gives syntax error

Tags: eclipse, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This is the xpath copied from chrome

//*[@id="inputText"]

and this is how i am using in Eclipse selenium webdriver and its giving me syntax error

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id="inputText"]")
```

Comment: And the programming language you are using is what? Eclipse is used for many different languages.

Comment: `@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='inputText']")` or `@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"inputText\"]")` - I hope this will not show error.

Comment: Just use single quotes for the value of id

Comment: thanks resolved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`xpath`** you picked from `Chrome Dev Tools` is correct which is :

```
//*[@id="inputText"]
```

Now to implement the **`xpath`** in your code you have follow the `Java Convention` as follows :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='inputText']")
```

Comment: @Maddy Great News !!! Please Upvote this/any Answer which is useful to you.